# nWidart/laravel-modules, how to put the modules under different folders

Tags: laravel, module, subdirectory

I am new on Laravel. I want write modules on different folders, not all of them inside the same folder "Modules". For example:

```
myProyect
 |___ Clients
 |       |__ Module1
 |       |__ Module2
 |
 |___ Factory
         |__ Part1
         |_____Module1
         |____ Module2
         |__ Part2
         |____ Module1
```

Is it possible? I am trying, but I only get errors.
( I started with Clients becouse not have differents sub folders like Factory )
I am doing this:
Create a modular structure using nWidart steps. And it creates everything inside "Modules".
I did make new dir Clients and move second module to new folder, add in composer.json:
"autoload": {
"psr-4": {
"App\": "app/",
"Modules\": "Modules/",
"Clients\": "Clients/"
},
And on config/app.php, I wrote:
Clients\Module1\Providers\Module1ServiceProvider::class,

and when I wrote: composer dump-autoload , this error ocurrs:
Class 'Clients\Module1\Providers\Module1ServiceProvider' not found

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You can set different modules in sub folders in Modules directory. You must set config in module.php :

```
    'scan' => [
    'enabled' => false,
    'paths' => [
        base_path('vendor/*/*'),
    ],
],
```

change path like this:

```
    'scan' => [
    'enabled' => false,
    'paths' => [
        base_path('Modules/Clients/*'),
        base_path('Modules/Factory/*'),
    ],
],
```

Then change other path config:

```
'modules' => base_path('Modules/Clients'),
'assets' => public_path('modules/Clients'),
```

And namespace:

```
'namespace' => 'Modules\Clients',
```

Now if you run `php artisan module:make Test` Test module set in Clients directory.

You can set modules , assets, namespace config path in controller:

```
    \Config::set('modules.paths.modules',base_path('Modules/Clients'));
    \Config::set('modules.paths.assets',base_path('modules/Clients'));
    \Config::set('modules.namespace','Modules\Clients');
```

Check composer.json, add the autoloading to it:

```
  "autoload": {
"psr-4": {
  "App\\": "app/",
  "Modules\\": "Modules/"
   }
}
```

Then run `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: Great! Thanks Zahra! I will try on my next project.

Answer (score 0):

I have something similar.

I need to use the same module in more than one project.

in the following example "Module1" is used in both Project1, Project2 and Project3.
My mass structure would be close with the following:

```
PROJECTS
 |___ Project1
 |___ Project2
 |___ Project3
 |___ Module1
```

I would like to keep this structure as it follows the company's standard.

I tried some changes in my modules.php but without success:

```
'namespace' => '',
    'paths' => [
        'modules' => base_path('../..')
    ]
```

I got the following return:

PS C:\1.PHP\PROJECTS\PROJECT> php artisan module:list

```
 Error 

  Class '\Teste\Providers\TesteServiceProvider' not found

  at C:\1.PHP\GLOBAL\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\ProviderRepository.php:208
    204▕      * @return \Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider
    205▕      */
    206▕     public function createProvider($provider)
    207▕     {
  ➜ 208▕         return new $provider($this->app);
    209▕     }
    210▕ }
    211▕

  1   C:\1.PHP\GLOBAL\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\ProviderRepository.php:144
      Illuminate\Foundation\ProviderRepository::createProvider("\Teste\Providers\TesteServiceProvider")

  2   C:\1.PHP\GLOBAL\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\ProviderRepository.php:61
      Illuminate\Foundation\ProviderRepository::compileManifest()
```